# R-Pi ZeroW with Adafruit I2S DAC bonnet - reassign GPIO pins for I2C?

Tags: i2c

Couldn't find this covered elsewhere.  Grateful for any pointers or an example please...

Is it possible to use (say) dtoverlay to reroute three GPIO input signals to use three spare hardware pins ?  Currently these three signals occupy the pins that will be used for a I2C interface which the sound bonnet uses (ie. GPIO18, 19 and 21).

It's unclear from the documentation I've read whether the I2C signals are movable.

Comment: You mention both I2S and I2C.  They are different things.  Which of those signals do you wish to move to alternative pins?

Comment: Thanks Joan, yes I should have been clearer.

Comment: Its an I2S sound 'bonnet' which uses the three I2C GPIO pins.  Those pins are already allocated to my ADC, so I wondered if it's possible to move the I2C signals to unused GPIO pins. 

G.

Comment: Still confused.  There are only two signals on the I2C bus (SDA and SCL).  GPIO 18/19/21 may be used for I2S.   They have no hardware support for I2C.

Comment: Sorry Joan.  To approach the problem the other way round, basically the question is can I have reasonable sound without involving pins GPIO12-23, which are already used for SPI transfers by my 12-bit ADC.